# Undefined result - Getting data from phpmyadmin using dialogflow

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm working on a project to retrieve data from phpmyadmin by using Dialogflow.
I've been following a tutorial on YouTube.
However, the results after performing a very simple query is undefined.
Here is my code

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const mysql = require('mysql');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  function connectToDatabase(){
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: '***.***.***.***',
      user: '*************',
      password: '*********',
      database: '****************'
    });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.connect();
      resolve(connection);
    });
  }

  function queryDatabase(connection){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM Data', (error, results, fields) => {
        resolve(results);
      });
    });
  }

  function handleReadDB(agent){
    return connectToDatabase()
    .then(connection => {
      return queryDatabase(connection)
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        connection.end();
      });
    });
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('ReadDB', handleReadDB);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

the results show something like this

3:10:29.505 PM
outlined_flag
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
Function execution took 1296 ms, finished with status code: 200

3:10:29.503 PM
info
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
 undefined

Please help

Comment: IMO, the connection to the database is failing. Are you trying to connect to a local MYSQL Database?

Comment: I notice you're not checking the error response for anything. Can you try adding logging for the error and update the question to report on what it is saying?